# FormData append is removing String qouts angular

Tags: node.js, angular, multipartform-data, joi

when creating a formdata after appending data using .append() the value gets appended but after the value is send over HTTP the body is like

{
ProductName: Pname
}

instead of
{
ProductName: "Pname"
}

which in result is failing my JOI node validation in .string().

PS the reason of using FormData is i also need a file to be uploaded with the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
async create(@UploadedFiles() files, @Body() dto: any): Promise<any> {
    try {
        return await this.educationService.create(JSON.parse(dto.objectDto), files);
    } catch (e) {
        throw new HttpException(e.message, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Try something like this you have to parse the object from frontend request because its content-type is form data(JSON.parse(dto.dto)).